# CodeIgniter: custom email function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have to sent email notification on various event. Like when insert record, update record, delete record events.

**Working Code:**
*This I am using in controller and it is working fine with no issue*

```
$email_hr       = $this->config->item('hr_email_templates');
$email_template = $this->config->item('employee_new_email');

$message = $this->load->view($email_hr . $email_template, $data, true);

$this->email->clear();
$this->email->from('system@myemail.com', get_config_option('site_name'));
$this->email->to(get_user_data('email', 1));
$this->email->subject(get_config_option('site_name') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('employee_new_subject'));
$this->email->message($message);

if ($this->email->send()) {
    // do the stuffs
}
```

Since I have to repeat this in many more controllers (events) I thought to make a function to make my life easier. So I made it as below. But this is not working at all and not sending any email.

**Function**

```
function email_notification($subject, $message, $to = FALSE, $from = FALSE, $from_name = FALSE)
{
    $to        = isset($to) ? $to : get_user_data('email', 1);
    $from      = isset($from) ? $from : 'system@myemail.com';
    $from_name = isset($from_name) ? $from_name : get_config_option('site_name');

    $CI = get_instance();

    $CI->email->clear();
    $CI->email->from($from, $from_name);
    $CI->email->to($to);
    $CI->email->subject(get_config_option('site_name') . ' - ' . $subject);
    $CI->email->message($message);

    return TRUE; // also tried using return TRUE
}
```

**Usage**

```
$email_hr       = $this->config->item('hr_email_templates');
$email_template = $this->config->item('employee_new_email');

$message = $this->load->view($email_hr . $email_template, $data, true);

email_notification($this->lang->line('employee_new_subject'), $message, get_user_data('email', 1));//get_user_data($field, $id)
```

The above function not sending any email and so this

```
if ($this->email->send()) {
    // do the stuffs
}
```

never get true which stop executing some stuffs and no email

Comment: you have made that function in `helper` or `library` or in `controller` ?
you are using wrong method to call that function.

Comment: I have made it in helper. Oh but since I am loading email library by default, do I need to load library?

Comment: you need to load helper first (its not in `usage` code you posted)  have you kept it in `autoload.php` ?

Comment: Yes the helper has been auto loaded already.

Comment: The email_notification function doesn't actually send the email (looking at your code). "return ($this->email->send()) ? true : false;"

Comment: @Craig Yeah it is not sending. Could you please help me to make it works?

Comment: @CodeLover `print_r($CI->email->print_debugger());exit();` instead of `return true` in your function and post results.

Comment: @karanthakkar its `exit()` and stop executing anything.

Comment: @CodeLover not sure why not working , but i copied your function and its working, weird issue.

Comment: Yes it is weird to me as well. Let me try to rewrite everything once again and see what will I get.

Comment: oh damn big blunder, how i missed this `isset($to) ? $to : get_user_data('email', 1);` is wrong you should use `$to ? $to : get_user_data('email', 1);` because FALSE will also set it. (in all 3 isset) and try to pass first 3 parameters.it might not solve your problem but its a mistake. sorry for such late recognition.feeling gutted. :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the email isn't being sent in the email_notification function.

```
function email_notification($subject, $message, $to = FALSE, $from = FALSE, $from_name = FALSE)
{
          $to        = isset($to) ? $to : get_user_data('email', 1);
          $from      = isset($from) ? $from : 'my@email.com';
          $from_name = isset($from_name) ? $from_name : get_config_option('site_name');

          $CI = get_instance();

          $CI->email->clear();
          $CI->email->from($from, $from_name);
          $CI->email->to($to);
          $CI->email->subject(get_config_option('site_name') . ' - ' . $subject);
          $CI->email->message($message);

          // SEND THE EMAIL....
          return $CI->email->send();
      }
```

**Edit**

This is a working function which I use to send emails, but I use it as a library, not a helper.

```
function send_email($subject, $message, $to = null, $from = null, $from_name = null)
{
      $this->load->library('email');

      $config = array( 
                'wordwrap' => false,
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'crlf' => "\r\n",
                'newline' => "\r\n" 
      );

      $this->email->initialize($config);

      if ( ! $from ) { $from = 'from@emailaddress.com'; }
      if ( ! $from_name ) { $from = 'from name'; }
      if ( ! $to ) { $from = 'myemail@address.com'; }

      $this->email->from($from);
      $this->email->subject($subject);
      $this->email->to($to);

      $this->email->message($message);

      $this->email->send();                    
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not sending yet... I really don't understand what it is like that

Comment: Actually, I already tried that by using `$CI` instead of `$this`

Comment: Have you tried the print_debugger function, to see what the problem is?

Comment: I just tried after you said but it is not outputting any message.